# How to stop (xhr) processes in cypress?

Tags: cypress

When I run my test file in cypress, I noticed that except running my commands, it runs also many xhr commands. Is there a solution to stop (not run) xhr?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's you app that triggers the xhr POST calls.

You can prevent them going out to the server with `cy.intercept()`, but be careful not to stop anything that will break the app.

Ref [StaticResponse](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#staticResponse-lt-code-gtStaticResponselt-code-gt)

> By passing in a StaticResponse as the last argument, you can statically define (stub) a response for matched requests

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'https://mc.yandex.ru/webvisor/**', {})  // stub the yandex calls
cy.visit(...)
```

The log entries will still show. If this is your concern (not stubbing), you will need to hook into log events. Please advise.

Comment: Should I intercept it before my commands or after? Imagine I have there "type" command.

Comment: Before - always call intercept before the thing that triggers the xhr.

Comment: But if the xhr are caused by `.type()` then maybe it's part of the functionality and you don't want to stub them.

Comment: No, it's not part of functionality. Is it possible to intercept all POST request before a command? For example, I have there some more requests except only yandex. Should I intercept them one by one?

Comment: Can try smaller match string like `cy.intercept('POST', 'https://mc.yandex.ru/**', {})` or `cy.intercept('POST', '**/webvisor/**', {})`. Find correct match string is tricky without actual website to test.